# Randomize value of given key of Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, random

So I am practicing python and I'm using a tutorial where you create a terminal based game using python. I'm trying to not follow it letter for letter so I can learn it better. In it I have 2 dictionaries, one for the 'Monster' and 'Player'

```
 player = {'name': 'Kevin', 'attack': 10, 'heal': 16, 'health': 100}
 monster = {'name': 'Grog', 'attack': 12, 'health': 100}
```

I want to randomize the 'attack' damage between a set number, how would I implement that?

Comment: Note that with Thomas's suggestion, whatever *applies* the damage is responsible for generating the random number between 8 and 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **random** to generate random numbers or choices.

```
import random
r_num = random.randint(a,b)
```

*Return a random integer N such that a <= N <= b*.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, change your dictionary to:

```
player = {'name': 'Kevin', 'attack': [8, 12], 'heal': 16, 'health': 100}
```

And the code to chose your attack damage:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.uniform(*player['attack'])
```

> 10.240264593076365

Please note that 12 will be excluded from the range.

Comment: Is there any way I can get a nice rounded number without a decimal?

Comment: why would you use an external lib like numpy for such a simple task anyway? When you just need a random int, it seems a lot better to use `random.randint(a, b)`.

Comment: @hello_fr1end yes you're right, I could have used `random.uniform`, I'm just getting too used to numpy.

Answer (score 0):

If you ever want to pick a number that doesn't come from a consecutive range, use `random.choice`:

```
import random
random.choice(range(0,101,5))
```